# Add edges to Openmesh mesh

Tags: c++, openmesh

Just starting out with OpenMesh, and I have so far been able to add vertices, and make faces. **I now have a problem with understanding how i should add an edge to the mesh.**

I am aware of the Half-edge datastructure that openMesh uses, but i can't really understand how i should add the edge..

**Code:**

Definitions:

```
    Variables in header:
    vector<OpenMesh::PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT<OpenMeshExt::MyOwnTraits>::VertexHandle> vHandlers;
    OpenMesh::PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT<OpenMeshExt::MyOwnTraits> myMesh;
```

In cpp:

```
typedef OpenMesh::PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT<OpenMeshExt::CustomTraits> OpnMesh;
typedef OpnMesh::VertexHandle vertexHandle;

void Mesh::addVertexFromPoint(Point& position){
    float x = static_cast <float> (position.x());
    float y = static_cast <float> (position.y());
    vertexHandle vhand= myMesh.add_vertex(OpnMesh::Point(x,y,.0f));
    vHandlers.push_back(vhand);
}

void Mesh::makeFace(){
    if(vHandlers.size()<=2){
        return;
    }
    myMesh.add_face(vHandlers);
//Add edges between eg vertex 0 and 1 in vHandlers (vector with VertexHandlers) 
}
```

Have searched the documentation, but can't really say I found the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to/you can't explicitly create or delete edges. Whenever you modify the mesh e.g. by creating a face with `add_face`, the mesh will create (or delete) the necessary (half-)edges. Also, it will adapt the links between the vertices, edges and faces to reflect the topology of your mesh.